# Disabling SCM in sonar.properties doesn't work

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.6

It seems that adding `sonar.scm.disabled=true` to the conf doesn't not work. The sonar-scanner will report the following error:

> ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error when executing blame for file
>   betamao/betamao/admin.py  at
>   org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.blame(SvnBlameCommand.java:86)
>     at
>   org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.blame(SvnBlameCommand.java:59)
>     at org.sonar.batch.scm.ScmSensor.execute(ScmSensor.java:86)     at
>   org.sonar.batch.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:57)
>     at
>   org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58)
>   ...

I still have to disable SCM in "General Settings > SCM" administration page to make it work.

Is this a bug?

My environment is:

sonar-scanner 3.0.3.778 with openjdk8-u131

sonarqube-5.6.6lts with openjdk8-u131

Comment: Why would you think `disable=false` should turn anything _off_?

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam
I'm sorry for my editing mistake, It should be `sonar.scm.disabled=true`, and I correct it in my question above.

the dosc [link](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/SCM+support) discribed that
`It is possible to disable SCM support in the "General Settings > SCM" administration page or setting property sonar.scm.disabled=true during project analysis.`.
so i think `disabel=true` maybe the same effect as SCM settings on page?

Comment: @mangobowl is it a single module project? You defined the property in the  file sonar-project.properties?

Comment: Please provide more details about where exactly you added `sonar.scm.disabled=true`. As it stands, it's not clear, and I suspect you most probably added it not at the right place, that's why it's not taking effect.

Answer (score 6):

If you're building your project with [Gradle](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.sonarqube), you can use the property `sonar.scm.disabled`.

For example, set it in your `build.gradle`:

```
// Let SonarQube analyze the project
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.projectKey", "YourProjectId"

        property "sonar.projectName", "Your Project"

        property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"

        // For SVN projects, SonarQube would run "svn blame" to know
        // who changed which parts of the code. Without authorization
        // this fails, so we disable it
        property "sonar.scm.disabled", "True"

        // Address of the SonarQube server
        property "sonar.host.url", "localhost:9000"
    }
}
```

You can also pass the property via the command line to Gradle:

```
./gradlew sonarqube -Dsonar.scm.disabled=True
```

Comment: I am adding it in Java_Opts (Command line args). as -Dsonar.scm.disabled=True

Should it be ```true``` or ```True```

Which is correct, or will both work?

Comment: @SumukhBhandarkar: I can't answer that with certainty because I'm not working with SonarQube anymore. I'd use capitalized "True" like I did in the answer.